# Laravel 5.3 file response error

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to open a PDF doc inline in the browser from an S3 bucket using a File Response like so...

```
public function showReport(Document $document)
{
    return response()->file("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" . $document->path . '/' . $document->file_name . '.' . $document->ext);
}
```

But I'm getting this error...

> does not exist in
>   /var/www/ssiweb/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:37

But I can access the document if I just drop it into a browser.  Does the file method not accept a url?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, Not sure but may this work for you.

```
public function showReport(Document $document)
{
  $file_path = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/" . $document->path . '/' . $document->file_name . '.' . $document->ext;
    if (File::isFile($file_path))
    {
        $file = File::get($file_path);
        $response = Response::make($file, 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

        return $response;
    }
    //Not a file....
}
```